# android relative layout issue with button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have below relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivider"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buttonDivider"
        android:text="Open" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonDivider"
        android:text="Close" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And it generates button like this:

[image]

I tried modifying properties, given enough time but can't get it right :(

How can I make it so three buttons appear in sequence while equally occupying width from parent (currently they are not equally distributed as shown in image):

```
Open Delete Close
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use relative layout. The solutions is:

1. Use a horizontal linear layout for the parent layout.
2. Set `android:weightSum="3"` for the linear layout.
3. For each button set `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`. This will distribute them evenly.

Comment: Thanks did that but now getting `Buttons in button bars should be borderless; use style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"` ?

Comment: Hi @Szymon,I think without set this android:weightSum="3" properties we also getting same out put but have to gave as equal layout weight for all three button...

Comment: @Haresh yes, that's right. I just like to keep things explicit for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve your requirement using `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_weight` attribute as follows...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Open" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" >

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dip" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/buttonDivider"
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buttonDivider"
    android:text="Open" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnOpen"
    android:text="Delete" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:text="Close" />
```

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout is much easier to use in such case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Open" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Close" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that to be center horizontal or vertical or both  give its respective property to the parent relative layout.

Both Center Vertical or Horizontal- `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

```
Horizontal- android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
Vertical- android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code with following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" >

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dip" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/buttonDivider"
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Open" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Delete" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Close" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOpen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Open" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delete" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Close" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```